# CSS weird spacing behavior when cropping images

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

The images I'm working with are 350 x 525 px, but the top and bottom 90ish pixels of the image are transparent, which makes the actual content roughly 350 x 350 px in the center of the png. I want to show the 350x350 content with rounded corners, so I have the following CSS which does the trick:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

The code basically removes the top and bottom bezels and gets me a 1:1 aspect ratio image with rounded corners. The problem now is that the `<div>` housing this image stays the same height, so when I arrange these images in a grid, I get a lot of empty space that I don't know how to fix.

I am working with React and styled-components, but this is the equivalent HTML and CSS:

This is the main grid container.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}
```

And each element in the grid is called a card. Here's how each card is defined.

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="image-path" alt="" />
    <h4>some text</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

I've attached a few images of the issue. How do I fix this?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8AhM.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHl8H.png)

Comment: try this `.card {
    margin-bottom: -40%;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

As per [Максим Мовчан](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15631593/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD)'s answer

try this

```css
.card { 
  margin-bottom: -40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` to `max-content` for your `a` tag.

CSS:

```
a {
  height: max-content;
}
```